# SQL Server: BACKUP MASTER KEY produces different output every time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I ran this on a new DB:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '27c381e5-27cf-483f-81bf-143845911a5f';

BACKUP MASTER KEY TO FILE = 'c:\temp\key1.key'
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '27c381e5-27cf-483f-81bf-143845911a5f'

BACKUP MASTER KEY TO FILE = 'c:\temp\key2.key'
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '27c381e5-27cf-483f-81bf-143845911a5f'
```

However, the backups are different:

```
C:\Windows\system32>type c:\temp\key1.key | md5sum
702f95c38ea9b740ebaa7e186b9c12ec *-

C:\Windows\system32>type c:\temp\key2.key | md5sum
31906913d9d7c15fc1ba90a9635fee52 *-
```

I did hex-dumps, too, and the files aren't remotely similar.

Can someone explain this behavior? I'm trying to do a backup and restore and I can't seem to figure out how this process is supposed to work. The restores are failing and it appears that I can't even figure out what's going on with the backup.

Comment: And the error you receive during the DMK restore is...

Comment: It's not restoring. If the key doesn't work then you just get NULL. I'd imagine it's because the backupdata is different even when the key and content don't change, which is the original question. Can't debug the restore until we can account for the weirdness in the backup. Any idea?

Comment: I can't confirm, but most encryption algorithms use a salt to protect against rainbow table-type attacks. You may be running into that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR:

It is normal for cipher text to be different on each encryption, all other things being equal. I believe this is intentional "randomisation" of the output in order not to make password guessing easier. (The signature, however, will always be the same.)

If you will look at your DMK backup files' contents side by side, you will see that the first 40-60 bytes have almost identical structure (same amounts of spaces in the same places, for instance); only some data differ. This is a header where the salt, among other things, is located. Salt doesn't need to be hidden; it only needs to be random.

---

Now about the errors you receive during the restore which, for some reason, cannot be made known. I have created the test environment and two DMK backups just as you did. In addition, in order to make things a bit more realistic, I created a certificate without specifying the encryption password:

```
create certificate [TestCert] authorization [dbo]
    with subject = 'DMK Restore Test certificate';
```

This means that the certificate private key will be encrypted using the DMK, so now we have some encrypted data. If I try to restore the DMK from its first backup:

```
restore master key from file = 'D:\Tests\Key1.dmk'
    decryption by password = 'asdfdgkjh98hvio'
    encryption by password = 'nmbneknfownoih';
```

SSMS outputs the following message (not an error, mind you):

> The old and new master keys are identical. No data re-encryption is required.

The key is currently open, because it's a default behaviour, and no differences are detected. Trying to create a signature using our cert proves that data encrypted by DMK (cert's private key) is accessible:

```
select signbycert(cert_id('TestCert'), 'ASDfgh');
```

(You will see some `varbinary(128)` output for the above).
However, if I turn off the key auto-opening by removing its copy from the `master`, which is a common scenario when you restore the database backup:

```
alter master key drop encryption by service master key;
```

and then try to restore using the same `restore master key` statement as above, there will be an error, indeed:

> Msg 15329, Level 16, State 30, Line 1
>
> The current master key cannot be decrypted. If this is a database
>   master key, you should attempt to open it in the session before
>   performing this operation. The FORCE option can be used to ignore this
>   error and continue the operation but the data encrypted by the old
>   master key will be lost.

The keys (existing and the one being restored) are still the same, but this time SQL Server can't see it - the DMK is closed. Trying to sign using the cert returns `NULL` for the same reason. Note the mentioning of the `FORCE` option. If I add it:

```
restore master key from file = 'D:\Tests\Key1.dmk'
    decryption by password = 'asdfdgkjh98hvio'
    encryption by password = 'nmbneknfownoih'
    force;
```

the result is, again, just an informational message:

> The current master key cannot be decrypted. The error was ignored
>   because the FORCE option was specified.

The only thing left to get your data back is to either explicitly open the DMK, or turn its auto-opening back on:

```
open master key decryption by password = 'nmbneknfownoih';
go
-- And if you need it to be always available in the future
alter master key add encryption by service master key;
go
```

After that, certificate signing starts to work again (and will return exactly the same binary data as it did the first time).

Comment: Thanks for laying that out, Roger. I'd expect that, though repeated encryptions might be salted, backups (read: a one-time encryption for data passing between systems that don't necessarily have any previous knowledge of each other) *specifically* not be salted. I've never seen that type of data be salted. How can a backup be randomly salted if we might be restoring somewhere else? How does that work?

Comment: It's not that I'm hiding an error that I'm seeing, it's just that I, as someone who is not familiar with MSSQL encryption, witnessed someone else, who is also not familiar with this functionality (though extremely intelligent and and not prone to boneheaded oversight), try to backup and then restore the key using a couple of basic statements. After he did this, we selected from the table and our values were presenting as NULL. I then noticed the key dissymmetry. Clearing we're missing steps, so I appreciate the walkthrough. **Maybe this merely required the key to be opened first?**

Comment: @DustinOprea, added some explanation to clarify points mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, Roger, though that seems inverted. If the salt is the same, then, even if there's more to the header and some of it differs, shouldn't the encrypted portion be identical?

Comment: Well, not "exactly" identical, of course. I mean, it looks like some sort of a header with identical structure - same amounts of spaces in the same places, for instance. Salts and other variable parameters are different, but the structure is the same. And when the actual encrypted data starts, there are no similarities at all - binary sequences are completely different.